# Convert form text in image - canvas

Tags: javascript, forms, image, reactjs, vue.js

I'm trying to create a simple application that converts the filled data from form to image.
For example: I have a form with all data filled in dynamically. When I click submit I want to convert the result of the filled fields into an image.

Can I do this only with javascript, vue.js or react?

Example:

[image]

- This issue was treated as a duplicate, but I believe that the others that were dealt with did not address the same issue that I do. 
  Upon filling out the form dynamically, (the user types and sees how it is in the image) and after saving the image on his machine. And yet, whether this can be done in react, or vue only.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas can be used to create images programmatically.

This can be easily achieved using react-canvas library.

```
const ReactCanvas = require('react-canvas');
const Surface = ReactCanvas.Surface;
const Image = ReactCanvas.Image;
const Text = ReactCanvas.Text;
class MyComponent extends Component{
     render(){
       const surfaceWidth = window.innerWidth;
       const surfaceHeight = window.innerHeight;
       return(
          <Surface width={surfaceWidth} height={surfaceHeight} left={0} top{0}>
            <Text>
             Text Data from Your form component
            </Text>
          </Surface>
       )
     }
    }
```

Comment: I'm trying to use the canvas, however I need to set styles for various texts and images within the page and with it, it seems to be not possible.

Comment: @virginiarcrz please check out react-canvas documentation. I will update answer with style guide(currently on mobile)